# Google Search Appliance search in Google Groups

Tags: google-search-appliance

I want to use GSA to serve search results from Google Groups.

I do a lot of research in the web but I did not found information about GSA and Google Groups. I understood that Google Groups use #! (Hashbang) in the URL and GSA doesn't support crawling AJAX applications.

I think that a solutions could be to use the [Integrating with Google Apps](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/integrating_apps/integrating_apps.html#1074233) method but on this, and other similar, article they talk about Google Sites and Google Docs and not about Google Groups.

Because to try this solution I have to involve various departments in the company I would like to know if someone used this method for that. Or if someone could give me some advices to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no API nor any existing oob stuff on the GSA to crawl Google Groups, the best way is to use the Google Adaptor framework and create something on your own. It should be fairly easy tbh.